# I can't get the touch coordinates

Tags: touch

I have a big problem. I have been trying to get the touch coordinates for hours. But it isn't worked. My code is:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    if (event. getAction ()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            touchx = event . getX   ();
        touchy= event . getY();


    }
    }
    return true;
    }

@Override
public void render()
{   
    touch=Gdx.input.isTouched();
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.begin();
    if(touchx>2){
    batch.draw(texture, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 4, 0, 
               Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2);

               }
               batch.end();
```

}

It doesn't work. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override 
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        int i=0;
        i++;

        System.out.println("-.-------------------X:"+event.getX()+"Y: "+event.getY());
        return true;
 }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation on your answer.